# Bug when programmatically adding PivotItem to Pivot + events on PivotItem Headers

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

I've run across quite the strange bug while trying to programmatically add `PivotItem`s to a `Pivot` in Windows Phone 8. PivotItems can be added willy-nilly as the app is first built, but as soon as it has had a half-second to start doing its thing, it starts throwing an `ArgumentException` whenever I try to call my Pivot's `_pivot.Items.Add(new PivotItem())`. The same thing happens with `Insert(x, new PivotItem())`.

This does not always work:

```
PivotItem testPivot = new PivotItem();
var tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Text = token.Substring(0, token.Length - 1);
tb.Hold += _page.EditPivots;
testPivot.Header = tb;
 _pivot.Items.Add(testPivot);
```

While this does:

```
PivotItem testPivot = new PivotItem();
testPivot.Hold += _page.EditPivots;
testPivot.Header = token.Substring(0, token.Length - 1);
_pivot.Items.Add(testPivot);
```

I seem to have pinned it down to only break in instances where the "Header" property is something other than a string. This seems to be a known bug, [as shown on the Microsoft Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/25aa23b6-5858-4b0e-807a-a5f287db003a/).

What I would like to know is, in order to circumvent this bug, how can I add an event handler to the `TextBlock` that the `PivotItem` generates when I make its `Header` a string?

Comment: What I don't understand is why you're creating these UI elements in procedural code instead of doing it the (right) way in XAML.

Comment: I assure you: there's a good reason and it really couldn't be done any other way.

Comment: Did you try the workaround suggested at the bottom of the thread you linked to? (i.e. collapse the Pivot, add the PivotItem, then reshow it)

Comment: I considered it-- I actually found the easier way to do it was to make the "Content" of the PivotItem a grid (instead of the Canvas I was planning on it being), then adding two elements to the grid: my original Canvas, then a transparent rectangle I'd place over the  Header at the top, to which I could then bind events.